# Type mismatch (Error 13) in Loop

Tags: vba, excel

Line 4 is messing my loop up with a type mismatch! What am I doing wrong?

```
For i = 4 To 8
    j = 20 + i
    Col = Columns(j)
    Range("'" & Col & "3'").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-11]=0,0,(IF(SUMIF(R3C2:R" & lRow & "C2, RC2,R3C" & i & ":R" & lRow & "C" & i & ")>RC[-11]*1000000, SUMIF(R3C2:R" & lRow1 & "C2, RC2,R3C" & i & ":R" & lRow & "C" & i & ")- RC[-11]*1000000,0)))"
Next i
```

Comment: What is the formula (in xlA1 style; not xlR1C1 style) that goes into the first cell and what are the 5 cells that you want to put the formula into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
For i = 4 To 8
    Cells(3, 20 + i).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-11]=0,0,(IF(SUMIF(R3C2:R" & lRow & "C2, RC2,R3C" & i & ":R" & lRow & "C" & i & ")>RC[-11]*1000000, SUMIF(R3C2:R" & lRow1 & "C2, RC2,R3C" & i & ":R" & lRow & "C" & i & ")- RC[-11]*1000000,0)))"
Next i
```

By using `Cells` or `Range` on their own Excel will assume you want to reference the active worksheet, in the active workbook. It's a much better idea to specify exactly which workbook/ worksheet you want the code to run on. E.g.:

```
For i = 4 To 8
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 20 + i).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-11]=0,0,(IF(SUMIF(R3C2:R" & lRow & "C2, RC2,R3C" & i & ":R" & lRow & "C" & i & ")>RC[-11]*1000000, SUMIF(R3C2:R" & lRow1 & "C2, RC2,R3C" & i & ":R" & lRow & "C" & i & ")- RC[-11]*1000000,0)))"
Next i
```

Answer (score 2):

You're doing many errors.

First, `col` is a column, not a (range address) string. You cannot concatenate a column to a string.

Second, you should not enclose a range address with single-quotes (`'`).

What you probably wanted to do is:

```
Cells(3, j).Formula = ...
```